# Sending message to user with FB Messenger Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

I want to send a messega to a specified user via fb messenger with intent.
I use android studio and i've tried this code:

I succeed with this code. How I can get the fb id (numbers) programatically?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/");
        uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri,"id here");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

This code open the program but I need to get fb id like in this site:
http://findmyfbid.com/. To use the intent and chat with different people.

Comment: what for? the user has to be able to select a user somewhere anyway, so why not just let him do it the official way? what´s the use case?

Comment: I found the solution, Can you help me to get my fb id (number) by code. This site do it online: http://findmyfbid.com/ @luschn

Comment: you should not ask questions in an answer, it´s a completely different question anyway that has been answered a LOT of times already ;) - anyway, that page is doing something illegal, it´s scraping the user profile. which is not allowed on facebook. you get the id by using /me/friends, and you can only get friends who authorized your app too. that illegal page gives you the "global id", you should not use that one for anything anymore - you can´t get it without scraping anyway.

Comment: I dont want to use that page. Is an example of the ID. I want to make an app that every user put his id on the profile. How i get MY id from the app

Comment: by authorizing yourself, plain and simple. after that, you get your id with a simple api call: /me

Comment: How can I write this call. I'm new on Android, I have the FB SDK and I logged in @luschn

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user

Comment: instead of user-id, just use "me"